# Is Megilas Eivah (Scroll of Hostility) available anywhere?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, prayer-book

About the Tosafos Yom-Tov, [Wikipedia writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom-Tov_Lipmann_Heller#Family):

> the Megillah that Heller wrote, called *Megilat Eivah* (Scroll of Hostility), that tells the story of his imprisonment and release, became a tradition for the descendants of Rabbi Heller. To this day, they celebrate the story of his life in a special Purim celebration.
>
> In 1984 on the 330th anniversary *Yahrzeit* of Rabbi Heller's death his autobiographical story of his imprisonment *Megillat Eivah* and a detailed family tree were published in English by Rabbi C.U. Lipschitz and Dr. Neil Rosenstein under the title, *The Feast and The Fast* by Moznaim Publishing Corporation, New York and Jerusalem.

Is this megilla available online anywhere, in original or English?

Comment: In Hebrew? Or the translated version you reference in the question?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/9529

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94

Comment: @JoelK Thanks. Added.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like answers to me.

Comment: http://www.living-museum.org/preview/artifact/32726/27796 seems to be a translation from family members in English ,good luck tracking it down.

Comment: @sam Nice find! The claim that " It has been in her family for forty generations." seems exaggerated as that makes the average generation less than 10 years, but hey ho. Anyway, my wife is a direct decendant too, so she should be entitled to obtain it… somehow.